# A word that means 'language and usage'

Tags: discussion, single-word-requests

As is known, when things aren't working the way you want them to, or you feel you're surrounded by problems, it can be tempting to look outward and try to change the things that you feel are causing issues.

And I feel the fact this site is called 'English Language & Usage' causes me some issues, particularly there is no space on my mobile screen to visualize that name entirely.

Then, even if no one will change that name, I'm wondering: Is there a word, one word, which means 'language and usage' combined?

Comment: If there were, and we here on English Language and Usage knew it, would we have named the site English Language and Usage, do you think?

Comment: @danbron No, as I pointed out in the third paragraph of my question ('*even if no one will change that name*').

Comment: Forget about changing it - if there was such a word, a shorter, simpler, clearer way of expressing L&U: do you imagine L&U would have been selected *in the first place*?

Comment: @danbron When EL&U started no more than two or three people were using a mobile device and, as a consequence, there was no need to choice a short name. So your in—the—first—place—argument is not an argument at all.

Comment: You're on a site *full* of people with large vocabularies and urges to flaunt them. Half the questions and answers here are single-word-requests. The urge to condense needed no external motivation from mobile devices. But anyway,  if directing your attention to the illogic of the question doesn't satisfy you, and you'd prefer me to provide a direct, flat, answer to it: *no*.

Comment: @danbron I want to provide you nothing, but, you know, mobile devices overtook fixed Internet access by may 2014. That's all.

Comment: Btw, EL&U started in Aug 2010 when in the third quarter alone there were 8.5 *million* iPhones sold.

Comment: If there is something about the site's name that bothers you, please post in meta. We're more than happy to hear of real problems there. Here, it sounds like a peeve or worse.

Answer (score 3):

Does it really matter if the name of the site fits entirely on a mobile screen?

If so, there's a bit of irony in you being the one who brought this to the community's attention. After all, your user name doesn't fit in the standard SE box:

[image]

I suppose, then, it shouldn't be so much of a big deal if the name of the site happens to be too long to fit on your phone.